# How can I combine single packages to one meta package on mac Terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, package, meta

I have multiple package files, which I created using pkgbuild

```
pkgbuild --root /path/folder1 --install-location /Folder1 ~/pkg1.pkg
pkgbuild --root /path/folder2 --install-location /Folder2 ~/pkg2.pkg
```

Now I want to combine pkg1.pkg and pkg2.pkg to one single meta package using command line utilities. Is there an easy way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: If having GUI is not matter, try http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Iceberg.html

Answer (score 2):

`productbuild` is the built-in tool for that. The [man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productbuild.1.html) is pretty helpful.

```
productbuild --package ~/pkg1.pkg --package ~/pkg2.pkg ~/both.pkg
```

If you need to do anything fancy like background images or conditional installation of component packages, you can also provide `productbuild` with a `Distribution` file. See [Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/Chapters/Introduction.html) for more information there.

Comment: Slight warning for those using the `distribution` technique, call `productbuild` from the directory of your `pkg` files, use relative paths, not absolute or you may just end up with a `16KB` installer and no bundled package.